# How to check if a uiimage view is added on a UIButton

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have taken all the images from photo gallery in an array and then shown all these images on UIButtons and putt them in scroll View to show a grid view.Now when user click the button it should look like as he selected that image, for that I have taken a tick mark image and added it in a UIImageView and added that image view on the button on its click. But now when user again click the same button then how to remove that UIImageview from button when user has already selected multiple images.
Here is my code

```
-(void)loadImagesOnScrollView
{
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(0, 55*[assets count]);

    int x=0,y=0;
    for (int i=0; i<[assets count]; i++) {
        ALAsset *asset = [assets objectAtIndex:i];

        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100);
        btn.tag=i;
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClkd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        if(i==0)
        {

        }
        else if(i%2 ==0)
        {
            x=0;
            y=y+110;
        }
        else
        {
            x=x+110;
        }

        [scrollView addSubview:btn];

    }
}

-(void)btnClkd:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if (sender.selected) {
        sender.selected=FALSE;
     }
    else
    {
        sender.selected=TRUE;
    }



    if(sender.selected)
    {

    [sender addSubview:imgView];

    }
    else
    {


    }

}
```

Along this I have one more question, how to set the content size of scroll view so as it can be adjusted with any number of images.

Comment: If(!sender.selected){[imgView removeFromSuperview];}

Comment: why are you using ur button tag for?

Comment: you can set your scroll view size by this line: scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(yourWidth,yourHeight);

Answer (score 2):

when you add an image on a button on selection, set its tag = constant (say 9999) + sender.tag.
Now again on click of button check if subview with tag 9999+sender.tag exists. If yes, remove that subview from superview

Answer (score 1):

Create a BOOL variable in your .h file eg:

```
BOOL isButtonClicked; // in .h file
```

then in your .m file

```
-(IBAction)onButtonClick:(UIButton *)checkBoxButton
    {
        if (!isButtonClicked) {
            [checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tickMark.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            isButtonClicked=YES;
        }
        else
        {
            [checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NormalImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            isButtonClicked=NO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Normal Image will always be there on button and now when user will click it then a tick mark will come over it to show user that this is selected that is why I have taken a tick mark image with blank background and added it on button as a subview on its click

Comment: ok cool..when you add the UIImageView(tickMark) give it a tag specifically  give it a distinct value eg :9999, so as it should not interfere with your button  tags.. and then in u r buttonClick method....                                                           for (UIView *v in button.subviews) {
                     if (v.tag == 9999) {
                NSLog(@"image found");
            }

Comment: thanks for your help but it wont work also as my requirement is like I have multiple buttons with different images on each now when user click a button then I will create a uiimage view and will add it on the clicked button now next time when this same button will be clicked again then that image view which was added on it should be removed from button now and the challenge is that button will be created dynamically depending on the no. of images available in the photo gallery so cant take the uiimageviews as global variables as I dont know in advance that how much will it be needed.......

Answer (score 0):

To check if UIImageView is added to an UIButton use the following..

for check if the button has any UIImage

```
 if ( [button.currentImage isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        NSLog(@"image exist");
    }
```

or

for check if the button has any background Image

```
 if ( [button.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        NSLog(@"background image exist");
    }
```

Comment: not working, even if detected that uiimage view is already added on the button then how will i remove it when i have already released it while adding it on the button

Comment: instead if     [sender addSubview:imgView];
why dont you just set the button.image

Comment: Because I need to put a tick mark on the original image, so as it look like as it is selected